# Make Anonymous Access for online SharePoint 2010 Team Site

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I have Online SharePoint 2013 Site and I would like to make it as Anonymous .Can any one help me how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous access is ONLY available for public site hosted on SharePoint (only one public site per Office 365 tenant)

it's not possible to implement anonymous access on other SharePoint sites (private) but you can invite external user (ie not Office 365 users)

**To configure a SharePoint Online site collection for anonymous access**

1) Login to Microsoft Office 365 as a tenant administrator.

2) On the home page of the site collection, choose MAKE WEBSITE ONLINE near the upper right corner of the page. This action also turns off the Use Remote Interfaces permission requirement.

**To configure an list or library for anonymous access**

1) Navigate to a list or library that the app for SharePoint that you are testing accesses and open the List Settings or Library Settings. For a SharePoint Online site, you must be logged in as a tenant administrator.

2) Choose Permissions for this list/library.

3) On the page that opens, choose Stop Inheriting Permissions on the Permissions tab, and then choose OK on the confirmation prompt.

4) Choose Anonymous Access on the Permission tab.

5) On the Anonymous Access form that opens, select all of the permissions that that users of the app for SharePoint require. You can grant permission to View, Edit, Add, and Delete items. You cannot grant Full Control, so anonymous users cannot change the schema of the list or change list settings.